# GOOGLE SHEET TELEGRAM character % or $

Tags: telegram-bot

Telegram Bot API with Google Sheets I HAVE PROBLEM  IN CODE
when  run telegram bot and   press on  show last expenses
if  i put  in chart in google sheet bot stack and never  show result

here is the code below

```
   var expenseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
 
   var expenses = [];
   var expensesSheet = expenseSheet.getSheetByName("Requests");
   var lr = expensesSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
   var counter = 0;
   for (var i = lr; i > 1; i--)
   {
     var date = expensesSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
     date = Date.parse(date);
     date = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(locale, {timeZone: timeZone});
     var description = expensesSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
     var cost = expensesSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
     var category = expensesSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
     var detalis = expensesSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
     var status  = expensesSheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
     var ticketid  = expensesSheet.getRange(i,10).getValue();
     
      

     expenses.push("\n---------\n"
       + "️ Date: <b>" + date
       + "</b>\n Category: <b>" + category
       + "</b>\n Description: <b>" + description 
       + "</b>\n Value: <b>& " + cost
       + "</b>\n Details: <b>" + detalis 
       + "</b>\n Ticket ID: <b>" + ticketid
       + "</b>\n  status: <b>" + status+"</b>");
     counter++;
     if (counter >= 1)
       break;
```